# Active Directory Connection C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, connection-string

My purpose is to connect to the Active Directory (which runs on a virtual machine (Win SRV 2008R2)) within a console C# application and write down all the user names in the domain. Since I'm a newbie on AD I just got stuck setting a connection.

Now first thing is first;

Root DomainName = frt.local

IP : 192.168.x.x

Username: admin

Pass : yyyy

I have written the code below to set a connection but getting errors. Please tell me the point I missed.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
entry.Path = "LDAP://192.168.x.x/dc=frt.local";
entry.Username = @"frt.local\admin";
entry.Password = "yyyy";
```

After pointing what I missed any help would be mostly welcome about writing down the usernames to the console.

Kind Regards

Comment: I see you have asked 4 questions before but did not accept answers for any of them. Try to increase your answer rate and it will encourage the users to answer.

Comment: Also, it might be worth posting the exception(s) you get in the body of your question.

Comment: @Tariqulazam thanks for the advice. I am actually not familiar on how to use the site.

Comment: You have already accepted one. So you are already on your way. Now as Jonners suggested, could you please update your question to include the exception you are getting?

Comment: I will when I get back to the office, promise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesim's answer is good - in the beginning. But I don't really see any point or need in using that

```
DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
```

line - the result of the PrincipalSearcher already is a UserPrincpial and you can access its properties much easier like this:

```
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(ctx)))
{
   foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
   {
       UserPrincipal foundUser = result as UserPrincipal;

       if(foundUser != null)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0}", foundUser.GivenName);
           Console.WriteLine("Last Name : {0}", foundUser.Surname);
           Console.WriteLine("SAM account name; {0}", foundUser.SamAccountName);
           Console.WriteLine("User principal name: {0}", foundUser.UserPrincipalName);         
           Console.WriteLine();
       }
   }
}
```

The `UserPrincipal` already and very nicely exposes the most frequently used attributes as properties on the object itself - no need for the rather messy code with the `DirectoryEntry`...

Answer (score 3):

```
  var username = "your username";
  var password = "your password";
  var domain = "your domain";
  var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, username, password);

  using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(ctx)))
  {
    foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
    {
      DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
      Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
      Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
      Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
      Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: See my response - not quite sure why you use `PrincipalSearcher` which returns a `Principal` - but then you go and get the underlying `DirectoryEntry` and have all that messy code to access its properties.... much nicer to just use the `UserPrincipal` object that you already get back from the `PrincipalSearcher` !!